# Python print function side-effect

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse some HTML with Russian letters. That's why i have headache with encodings.
I transform html text to tree using following code. Then i'm trying to extract some things from the page (header, arcticle content) using css queries.

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

doc = UnicodeDammit(html_text, is_html=True)
parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding=doc.original_encoding)
tree = html.fromstring(html_text, parser=parser)

...

def extract_title(tree):
   metas = tree.cssselect("meta[property^=og]")
   for meta in metas:       
       # print(meta.attrib)
       # print(sys.stdout.encoding)
       # print("123")    # Uncomment this to fix error
       content = meta.attrib['content']
       print(content.encode('utf-8')) # This fails with "[Decode error - output not utf-8]"
```

I get "Decode error" when i'm trying to print unicode symbols to stdout. But if i add some print statement before failing print then everything works fine. I never saw such strange behavior of python print function. I thought it has no side-effects. 
Do you have any idea why this is happening?
I use Windows and Sublime to run this code.

Comment: `encode()` is meant to encode unicode strings to bytes. The error states that `content` is not UTF-8. If you need to encode to bytes just drop 'UTF-8' and should work. Also remember that Python3 has a completely different I/O compared to Python2.

Comment: Printing Unicode text is platform-dependent, which platform are you using? And is that output going to a terminal?